# Schengen Visa - Schengen countries visit after UK visit

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, eu, indian-citizens

I have a 6 months UK Business visa. I need to apply for Schengen Visa to allow other EU countries travel. I will be travelling multiple time to Schengen countries for next 3-4 months and I have travelled to Schengen countries last year as well.

Now, till now, only 2 days of Belgium travel is confirmed for next month.

Can I apply for 4 months, multiple entries Schengen visas with those 2 days hotel confirmation? And am I eligible for 4 months Schengen multiple entry visa?

I am from India and plan to apply Schengen visa in India.

Comment: Your citizenship will play a role.  Though the general rule for Schengen Short Term visa is 90 days stay during any rolling 180 day period.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience any embassy is likely to grant you a short-term visa. It's also likely gonna be multiple entries because of your UK business visa. However, it's unlikely that you're gonna get the whole 4 months for just two days hotel confirmation. Also, I used to get multiple-entry visa for 2 months as well but they only allowed me to stay in Schengen area for 4 days based on my hotel confirmation. So, I can stay for 4 days and I have to go out and in again.

However, you mentioned that you're going to apply that from your home country. What I have said can change because of that as well. My sister used to get multiple-entry visa for 3 months with just 10 days hotel confirmation.

Also, as I have done this before. You can ask anything from the embassy but the final decision is their. I'd suggest ask for the maximum 90 days multiple entries. The worst case senario is they're going to get you 2-day visa for your Belgium trip.

Answer (score 2):

The confirmed travel plans for Belgium would for 2 days would be fine though without a longer confirmed stay they might simply issue a [Transit Visa](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/airport-transit-visa.html) though it's more likely a [Short Term will be issued](http://www.norwayemb.org.in/Embassy/Passports-and-Visas/Visa-Information-/Tourist-Visa/).

Generally speaking if you plan to travel multiple times you should not exceed 90 days total duration in any 180 day.  And the requirements for the visa you can see on any embassy site for the countries covered by the agreement.  I picked [Norway](http://www.norwayemb.org.in/Embassy/Passports-and-Visas/Visa-Information-/Tourist-Visa/).

If you need to stay more then 90 days in Europe you may have to pick a country and apply for a long term stay visa instead.